# Combining the elements of 2 lists

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

Assume we have two lists :

```
val l1=List("a","b","c")
val l2 = List("1","2","3")
```

What I want is : `List("a1", "b2", "c3")` that is, adding the nth element of l1 with the nth element of l2

A way to achieve it is :

```
(l1 zip l2).map (c => {c._1+c._2})
```

I just wonder if one could achieve it with an Applicative. I tried :

```
(l1 |@| l2) { _+ _ }
```

but it gives all the combinations :

```
List(a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3)
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Benoit

Comment: You want a ziplist.  Haskell has one at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors#ZipLists.  I'm not sure if Scalaz has one, but nor have I looked.

Comment: @DerekWyatt : Thanks Derek. missingfaktor has provided the answer

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that with strict lists, so instead use lazy lists i.e. streams. You have to define the `Applicative[Stream]` instance as shown below. (You'll find it in Haskell standard library under the name ZipList.)

```
scala> val s1 = Stream("a", "b", "c")
s1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[java.lang.String] = Stream(a, ?)

scala> val s2 = Stream("1", "2", "3")
s2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[java.lang.String] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> implicit object StreamApplicative extends Applicative[Stream] {
     |   def pure[A](a: => A) = Stream.continually(a)
     |   override def apply[A, B](f: Stream[A => B], xs: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = (f, xs).zipped.map(_ apply _)
     | }
defined module StreamApplicative

scala> (s1 |@| s2)(_ + _)
res101: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[java.lang.String] = Stream(a1, ?)

scala> .force
res102: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[java.lang.String] = Stream(a1, b2, c3)
```

The reason this cannot be done with strict lists is because it is impossible to define a `pure` on them that satisfies the applicative laws.

As an aside, Scala lets you do this more concisely than the code you have used in OP:

```
scala> (l1, l2).zipped.map(_ + _)
res103: List[java.lang.String] = List(a1, b2, c3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanations! As far as I understand, it works with  Streams because as they are lazy, their elements are procedeed one by one. Right?

Comment: @missinglake : Wah! You're far from being "lazy" on this forum! That is certainly "Reactive programming" :)

Comment: @bhericher, heh, thanks. :) By the way, it's missingfaktor, not missinglake.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you can't achieve this with an applicative as far as I can see. The applicative for list will apply the function  to all combinations, as you have found out. Not great for what you want but awesome for stuff like creating cartesian products.

A slightly less verbose method might use `Tuple2W.fold` supplied by scalaz:

```
(l1 zip l2).map (_ fold (_ + _))
```

Comment: Or `Tuple2#zipped`. Even more terse.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes : Thank you. If I correctly understand, scalaz allows to deal in a more convivial way with Tuples. That's pretty cool!